# Neck detection using opencv

Tags: opencv

Hi I am trying to detect the neck point in an image.I am using asm to detect the feature points of the face but i dont know how to detect the neck.Is there any algo or measurement to detect it?

```
//code ASM asmDetector.GetASMDetectedPoint(7, chin); 
asmDetector.GetASMDetectedPoint(4, leftCheek); 
asmDetector.GetASMDetectedPoint(10, rightCheek);

 //Neck detection 
float rightNeckX = rightCheek.x; 
float rightNeckY = chin.y + ((chin.y - rightCheek.y) / 2); 

float leftNeckX = leftCheek.x; 
float leftNeckY = chin.y + ((chin.y - leftCheek.y) / 2); 

leftNeck = CPoint2D(leftNeckX, leftNeckY); 
rightNeck = CPoint2D(rightNeckX, rightNeckY);
```

Comment: Explain with the code that you had tried until now...

Comment: Updated code in the question pls check

Comment: Look for something the same color as the face, immediately below the chin.

Comment: Wont work on all the cases.depends on what person is wearing...for collar T shirt it will work but for other cases like for girl hairs covering neck area.

Comment: give up. you can't *detect* the neck (there are no 'features', and it's always occluded by hair/clothing) you only can *infer* it from the data you already got.

Comment: have u got any solution ??.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching I did get better way to find the neck points. Please note that its not 100% correct and will go wrong in the profile images.

My approach was to use [Dlib](http://dlib.net/). Althought OpenCV is widely used for image processing but dlib has good support for image processing, what I like more about dlib is its simplicity.

Steps :

1. Get Upperbody haar cascade.
2. Collect around 100 images of upper body.
3. Start training with the tools provided in the dlib.
4. Basically you need to mark the point as per the omega shape, start from the left to right shoulder.

After training you will get the encoded dat file which can be used for the neck detection. All the solution and c++ implementation you will find in dlib solution.

I did the same training using ASM but result of dlib are more promising.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: can you provide any link to your project ??

Comment: I am stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case we can use OpenCV to detect face and then set the points to the lower of the face and then we can behave as the neck is detected...

Sorry but it's fact that there is no any other accurate way where you can detect neck perfectly.

If anybody have better idea then they people are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Haar classifier for face detection combined with a skin detector.
You just need then to subtract the face from the overall extracted mask containing the detected skin surface.

Answer (score -1):

What I had Done is trained a Dlib Model Using 71 Points(68 points of Dlib +2 Points for ear and 1 for neck)

[Demo Video Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vb1MfCnkKg62KtomY6jVAi9sseoA3ue8)

Comment: Link's broken. Getting 404.